# When an Essentials Vampire bites a random NPC, what happens?

Tags: dnd-4e, npc

Firstly, some backstory:

The party has recently released a large group of prisoners from a fortress orbiting Baator, and escaped with the freed prisoners on an Astral Ship of some sort. As is appropriate, they offered the poor souls places on their crew, and the prisoners accepted. However, one of the former prisoners is a Vampire played by a player who's character recently fell (it was a significant and awesome death, I promise). Partway into the journey, the player reveals to me that, while in captivity, he used his vampiric powers to bite and convert all of the other crew members.

I am woefully ignorant in Essentials, and am unprepared for this development. So far, I have just warned the party to keep the ship out of sunlight (is there even sunlight in the Astral Sea?), but if there is any official ruling on a PC Vampire spreading his loathsome malady, I would appreciate the enlightenment.

Comment: Is player running the class on his PC? the moves and class features will be explicit in what they do and don't do. Vampirism is not transferable by any of the attacks they would normally make and theres not really a feature to make thralls from what I remember. However are you asking a wider story question?

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith No, he's running him old-school. He didn't think there was anything in the book, and I thought that there might be something he or I missed/something on DDI (I haven't renewed my subscription for several years now). So yes, a wider story question.

Comment: http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/login.aspx?page=class&id=817 is the class. I'm not sure if it exists as a curse/disease in 4e. You are basically where "hear be dragons" as far as 4e is concerned if you are using previous edition's materials. You'll need to frame the question better in that case to highlight your goals and requirements for the interactions possible and more information on how his vampire class works (is it basically a race?)

Comment: Agreed with Joshua and voting to close until clarified. If you're using a houserule, we need a lot more information on how it works if we're to be any help (and even then it's iffy whether or not we can, since it's your rules anyway)